# How to resize bar chart based on no of x axis categories in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am working on adding some bar charts using the Highcharts . My chart looks kind of sparse when there are too few values in x-axis and too crowded if there are too many values.

I have fiddled with plotOptions options like  (pointPadding,groupPadding,borderWidth,pointWidt). This seems to prevent dynamic resizing of the bar to make it consistent but does not help with resizing the overall chart.

- Chart with Asia,America,Europe,Ocenaia,Africa looks like this

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Historic World Population by Region'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_population">Wikipedia.org</a>'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
        title: {
            text: null
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        visible:false
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' millions'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            },
            pointPadding: 0,
            groupPadding: 0,
            borderWidth: 0,
            pointWidth: 20
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled:false
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Year 1800',
        data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

- Chart with just Asia looks like this

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Historic World Population by Region'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_population">Wikipedia.org</a>'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Asia'],
        title: {
            text: null
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        visible:false
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' millions'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            },
            pointPadding: 0,
            groupPadding: 0,
            borderWidth: 0,
            pointWidth: 20
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled:false
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Year 1800',
        data: [635]
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

As one can see the chart with asia has a lot of unsued space and makes it look overall weird.

I want to see if anyone knows how can I change the overall height of the chart dynamically based on no of values in X-Axis categories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `chart.update()` method to add a new height based on bars amount. Check code and demo posted below.

Code:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    events: {
      load: function() {
        var chart = this,
          barsLength = chart.series[0].data.length;

        chart.update({
          chart: {
            height: 100 + 50 * barsLength
          }
        }, true, false, false);
      }
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Historic World Population by Region'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_population">Wikipedia.org</a>'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Asia'],
    title: {
      text: null
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    visible: false
  },
  tooltip: {
    valueSuffix: ' millions'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      },
      pointPadding: 0,
      groupPadding: 0,
      borderWidth: 0,
      pointWidth: 20
    }
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Year 1800',
    data: [107]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/x3e8brgq/1/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update